# Как отложить закачку файлов на сервер, вернуть пользователю ответ и затем докачать эти файлы?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Пытаюсь ускорить работу сайта с клиентом. Особенно тормоза проявляются при загрузке пользователем файлов изображений на сайт, если скорость отдачи у юзера маленькая. Как сделать, чтобы при отправке формы с файлами сервер сразу вернул true клиенту, а затем докачал файлы, а пользователь в это время мог бы продолжать пользоваться сайтом. Использую ajax. Сервер на laravel. Где такое можно реализовать: на сервере или на клиенте в js?

Comment: Файл в Blob и кусками отправлять

Comment: Никак. Такого функционала в браузерах нет.

Comment: Должно быть решение. Как тогда работают соцсети? Они мгновенно возвращают ответ и обновляют страницу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется **optimistic updates**. Суть заключается в том чтобы пользовательский интерфейс вел себя так, как будто изменение было успешно завершено до получения подтверждения от сервера о том, что это было на самом деле. Тоесть он с оптимизмом ожидает, что в конечном итоге получит подтверждение, а не ошибку.

Реализуется таким образом чтобы запрос отправлялся в фоновом режиме, а для пользователя выглядело так как будто картинка уже загрузилась (показать галочку, или отобразить картинку)

```js
const buttonElement = document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0];

const sendFileFunction = () => {
  buttonElement.classList.add("sending");
  
  // функционал по отправке запроса
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    buttonElement.classList.remove("sending");
    buttonElement.classList.add("success");
  }, 2000);
};

buttonElement.addEventListener("click", sendFileFunction);
```

```css
.submit {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit.sending::after {
  content: "...";
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
  animation: fadeInOut 0.8s infinite;
}

.submit.success::after {
  content: "✓";
  color: green;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="submit">Send file</button>
```

Comment: А как запустить отправку в фоновом режиме?

Comment: Обычный ajax запрос

Comment: Обновил с примером